# Simple submodule of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know that a simple right module is a non-zero right module $M_R$ whose submodules are only $M_R$ and $0$.

Now fix a module $N_R$. If I want to show that a submodule $M_R$ of $N_R$ is simple what do I need to show?

Think about the following ring $R$:

\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & 0\\
\mathbb{Q} & \mathbb{Q}
\end{pmatrix}
and consider the following submodule:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
\mathbb{Q} & 0
\end{pmatrix}

In my opinion it is not a simple module but it is a simple submodule of the left module $R$.

Comment: you need to show that itself is simple. i.e $M_R$ does not contain a proper submodule.

Comment: I don`t know if I have to show that $M_R$ does not contain a proper submodule of $M_R$ or $N_R$

Comment: You need to deal with proper submodules of $M_R$. However, if $K_R$ is a proper submodule of $N_R$ then $K_R\cap M_R$ is a submodule of $M_R $ but not necessarily proper submodule.

Comment: In my opinion there is a problem because a submodule of $M_R$ could not be a submodule of $N_R$.

Comment: In act they are, more generally the notion of submodule is a transitive relation.

Comment: I`m not sure.. I wrote an example.

Comment: In my opinion the problem is that if I have a submodule $M_R$ of $N_R$ you have to clarify if you consider a submodule of $M_R$ that only respect the product with the elements of $M_R$ (and so this is a submodules of $M_R$ in the structure of $M_R$) or respect the product with the elements of $N_R$ (and so this is a submodules of $M_R$ in the structure of $N_R$)

Comment: You got a little misconception between notion "submodule" and "ideal". Submodule is a subgroup of additive group which stables under scalar multiplication, that's mean a submodule of a submodule is indeed a submodule

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent condition for a nonzero (left) module $M$ to be simple is that, for each $x\in M$, $x\ne0$, we have $Rx=M$.

Now, for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
b & c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
q & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
qc & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This shows that the submodule generated by $x=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\q&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is the whole of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\\mathbb{Q}&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ for every $q\ne0$ (as a left module), because we can arbitrarily choose $c$.

Note that this is also a right module (being a two-sided ideal of the ring), but it is not simple as a right module.